# p:tooltip for items of p:pickList

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm struggling to use a primefaces `p:tooltip` for items of a `p:pickList`.

I have a pickList defined as:

```
<p:pickList id="stepPickList" 
            value="#{activityBean.stepDualListModel}"
            var="step"
            showSourceFilter="true" 
            showTargetFilter="true" 
            filterMatchMode="contains"
            itemLabel="#{step}" 
            itemValue="#{step}"
            addAllLabel="#{messages.label_addAll}"
            addLabel="#{messages.label_add}"
            removeAllLabel="#{messages.label_removeAll}"
            removeLabel="#{messages.label_remove}"
            moveBottomLabel="#{messages.label_moveBottom}"
            moveDownLabel="#{messages.label_moveDown}"
            moveTopLabel="#{messages.label_moveTop}"
            moveUpLabel="#{messages.label_moveUp}"
            showTargetControls="true">

    <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter" list="#{activityBean.stepSource}"/>

    <f:facet name="sourceCaption"> #{messages.step_list}</f:facet>  
    <f:facet name="targetCaption"> #{messages.label_stepList}</f:facet>

    <p:column style="width:100%;">  
        <h:outputText id="nameID" value="#{step.name}" /> 
        <p:tooltip for="nameID" value="#{step.description}" />
    </p:column>
</p:pickList>
```

This seems to show all tooltips for each item when mouse over the first element only...
I tried with primefaces extension's tooltip `pe:tooltip` and I get weird behavior too...

So, first of all, can a tooltip be used on h:outputText?
If not, what kind of component should I use?
(I tried with `h:outputLink` as seen in many examples on primefaces and pe showcases and still not the desired effect)

thanks for any hints !!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to replicate your error without the backing bean code, but have you tried

```
<p:column>  
    <h:outputText value="#{step.name}" title="#{step.description}" /> 
</p:column>
```

?

Comment: This has the expected behavior when over mousing the text except that title doesn't escape html formatted strings.  `step.description` comes from a `p:editor`.  That is why I wanted to use a tooltip !!